# ngrok - Error Connecting behind corporate proxy

Tags: ngrok

I am getting the following error, when I try to run ngrok behind corporate proxy.

```
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=info msg="open config file" path=C:\\Users\\XXX\\.ngrok2\\ngrok.yml err=nil
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="configured to dial out via HTTP Proxy" proxy_url=http://username:pass@proxyadd:port
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="starting component" obj=app name=web
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="starting component" obj=app name=console
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="starting component" obj=app name=updater
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="starting component" obj=app name="Tunnel session"
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="checking for updates periodically" obj=updater interval=6h0m0s
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="check for update" obj=updater
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=info msg="starting web service" obj=web addr=127.0.0.1:4040
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="waiting for update" obj=consoleui
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="Resize event, redrawing" obj=consoleui
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="waiting for update" obj=consoleui
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=eror msg="failed to reconnect session" obj=csess id=c17cebdb0468 err="Non-200 response from proxy server: 403 Forbidden"
t=2019-04-18T12:46:01+0530 lvl=dbug msg="sleep before reconnect" obj=csess id=c17cebdb0468 secs=0
```

Request your help to resolve

Comment: I am also getting the same error, did you fix this by any chance ?